# Error decoding image data

Tags: meteor, react-native

I receive url path from a meteor server and trying to display it. but onError logs

```
Error decoding image data <NSData 0x7f9d820c5a00; 1196 bytes>
```

I log the path and view it on browser and its there. what's causing it? or at least what does this error mean?

Edit:

I'm using meteorjs for server. I think its has something to do with it. I use static images online and it works just fine.

PS: I dont code in objective C

Comment: can you give image url?

Comment: i serve locally
http://localhost:3000/users/QtH3t7hrMk92D2BDN/medium_4980838804202467-EDDD9922-2ED4-42D3-B95D-AAFC9AFE5F64.jpg

something like that.

Comment: What is stored in the `NSData`?  I bet it's an error message, and not the image data.

Comment: show the code which you are useing?

Comment: @Avi I dont know. Its in react native code.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are directly displaying NSData without converting in to image. Do like this:

```
NSData *data = [NSData datawithContentsOfURL:URLString];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```